# Modification to a code to merge two parts of it with similar characteristics

Tags: php, regex, dom

Below is a link crawler that gets the urls of a page in a given depth. At the end of it I added a regular expression to match all the emails of the url that is just crawled. As you can see in the second part, it `file_get_content` the same page it just downloaded, meaning twice the execution time, bandwidth etc.

The question is how can I merge those two parts to use the first downloaded page, to avoid getting it again? Thank you.

```
function crawler($url, $depth = 2) {

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    if (!$parts || !@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url)) {
        return;
    }
.
.
.

//this is where the second part starts

  $text = file_get_contents($url);
  $res = preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i", $text, $matches);

}
```

Comment: Why not just `$contents = file_get_contents($url); if ( !$parts || !@dom->loadHTML($contents) ) { //...` and then reuse `$contents` at function end?

Comment: Do you think is quicker than replacing `$text = file_get_contents($url);` with `$text = $dom->saveHTML();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
$text = file_get_contents($url);
```

with:

```
$text = $dom->saveHTML();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php

Alternatively, in the first part of your function, you could save the HTML into a variable using `file_get_contents`, then pass it to `$dom->loadHTML`. That way you can then reuse the variable with your regex.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: Thank you, tested and working (the first part). Please explain me the benefits of this and suggest me any other merge.

Comment: These are the two best ways to avoid another call to the remote server. Either way will work. The first uses one less variable but requires extra processing of the imported HTML. The second avoids that processing but must store the HTML in an extra variable throughout. I think it's six in one hand, half a dozen in the other.

Comment: Which one do you suggest me if the web site is really big with a big crawling depth ? I run the script in a shared hosting. Can you edit mine or post the part for your second solution please?